# How to stop this javascript count down when finished?

Tags: javascript

I found this javascript and it starts a new count down after finished in a loop

```
<script>
  var countdownNumberEl = document.getElementById('countdown-number');
  var countdown = 10;

  countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;

  setInterval(function() {
    countdown = --countdown <= 0 ? 10 : countdown;
    countdownNumberEl.textContent = countdown;
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: What do you think `--countdown <= 0 ? 10 : countdown` does?

Comment: It's not a loop, it's interval timer. When your `countdown` value equals 0, it resets to 10 again and so on. You just need to assign `setInterval` to a variable and then `clearInterval` when value is `0`.

Comment: I edited your code with clearInterval() method on the other thread. Please see if it helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57041611/3506426

Answer (score 2):

SetInterval returns a unique ID.

`var intervalId = setInterval( function(){}, 1000);`

so, when you want it to stop, you will just call `clearInterval(intervalId)`

If you want to call it in the function itself, you need to just have the correct conditional to monitor when you want it to stop it you would need to reference the global or scoped identifier.

In your example, you are using a `countdown` variable.

So you can say something like:

`if (countdown <= 0) clearInterval(intervalId);`